# find locations of a bunch of elements

Tags: c++, string, performance, vector, location

I need to find locations 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 which they are storing as a string named 'line' and keeping in a string vector named 'info'. but my code doesnt work any wrong in my code?

```
string line;
vector<vector<string>>info;
for (int x = 0; x < info.size(); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < info[x].size(); y++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            if (info[x][y] == i)
            {
                cout << "row " << x;
                cout << "column " << y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or any alternative ways which are faster?
show me your code cause I am new in programming hard to understand your explanation, thank you.

Comment: You are comparing a string to an integer, that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an `int` to a `string`, which will not compare equally. You'll have to convert one to the other

```
// compare them as strings
if (info[x][y] == std::to_string(i))
```

or

```
// compare them as ints
if (std::stoi(info[x][y]) == i)
```

Answer (score 1):

I am interpreting your question to mean that you're looking for digits 0 through 9 in a string such as "abc012efg". In that case:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        if (info[x][y] == i)
```

Unfortunately, the character '0', in this string, is not an integer 0. It is '0', which is ASCII 48, and you're searching the string not for characters '0' through '9', but for octets 0 through 9, not the same thing.

A second bug in here is that you're also searching for digits 0 through 10, instead of 0 through 9. The above code snippet should probably read:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (info[x][y] == '0' + i)
```